# Is there a way to use on_audio_query and audioplayers packages together?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-developer-api

I was using just_audio for a musc player project but I realised that it does not support resume play. I have tried switching to audioplayers. However, unlike in just audio I cannot play the songs from their URI. I have tried packages to convert uri to filepath but it it had]snt been working.
how should I go about it??

I tried the `lecle_flutter_absolute_package` but I haven't really figured out how to reference the uri from the query.

this is part of my code

```
    future: _audioQuery.querySongs(
                  sortType: null,
                  orderType: OrderType.ASC_OR_SMALLER,
                  uriType: UriType.EXTERNAL,
                  ignoreCase: true,
                ),
                builder: (context, item) {
                  //Displays any errors
                  if (item.hasError) {
                    return Text(item.error.toString());
                  }

                  // Waiting for the content
                  if (item.data == null) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }

                  // 'Library is empty.
                  if (item.data!.isEmpty) return const Text("Nothing found!");

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: item.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      String artist =
                          getArtistFromSong(item.data![index].title);
                      Future<String?> filePath =
                          LecleFlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(
                              uri: item.data![index].uri.toString());

                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(item.data![index].title,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Kalum',
                            )),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          artist,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Badscript",
                              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                        ),
                        trailing: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz_rounded),
                        onTap: () {
                          audioPlayer
                              .play(DeviceFileSource(filePath.toString()));
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
```